# INotifyPropertyChanged wrapper

Tags: c#, wpf

I found some [solution](http://geekswithblogs.net/DavidVallens/archive/2011/04/01/building-viewmodel-facade-objects-part-2.aspx) of INotifyPropertyChanged wrapper but it doesnot do anything. What I am doing wrong? Name updating asynchronous but value in windows do not change. Why?*                                                                                  *

```
namespace WpfApplication1.ViewModel
{
class CustomerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IWeakEventListener
{
    private readonly Customer _customer;

    internal CustomerViewModel(Customer customer)
    {
        if (customer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("personModel");
        }

        _customer = customer;
        NotifyPropertyChangedEventManager.AddListener(_customer, this);

        Action Start = new Action(UpdateAsync);
        IAsyncResult result = Start.BeginInvoke(null, null);
    }
    private void UpdateAsync()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            _customer.Name = (++i).ToString();
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _customer.Name; }
        set { _customer.Name = value; }
    }

    public string JobTitle
    {
        get { return _customer.Work; }
        set { _customer.Work = value; }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion

    #region IWeakEventListener Members
    public bool ReceiveWeakEvent(Type managerType, object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventArgs pcArgs = e as PropertyChangedEventArgs;
        if (pcArgs != null)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(pcArgs.PropertyName);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    #endregion
}
public class NotifyPropertyChangedEventManager : WeakEventManager
{
    public static NotifyPropertyChangedEventManager CurrentManager
    {
        get
        {
            var manager_type = typeof(NotifyPropertyChangedEventManager);
            var manager = WeakEventManager.GetCurrentManager(manager_type) as NotifyPropertyChangedEventManager;
            if (manager == null)
            {
                manager = new NotifyPropertyChangedEventManager();
                WeakEventManager.SetCurrentManager(manager_type, manager);
            }
            return manager;
        }
    }

    public static void AddListener(INotifyPropertyChanged source, IWeakEventListener listener)
    {
        CurrentManager.ProtectedAddListener(source, listener);
        return;
    }

    public static void RemoveListener(INotifyPropertyChanged source, IWeakEventListener listener)
    {
        CurrentManager.ProtectedRemoveListener(source, listener);
        return;
    }
    protected override void StartListening(object source)
    {
        ((INotifyPropertyChanged)source).PropertyChanged += Source_PropertyChanged; return;
    }
    protected override void StopListening(object source)
    {
        ((INotifyPropertyChanged)source).PropertyChanged -= Source_PropertyChanged;
        return;
    }

    void Source_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        { CurrentManager.DeliverEvent(sender, e); };
    }
}
```

}

Customer

```
    public class Customer:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Work { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And Xaml code

```
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding Name}"></Label>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I've succesfully used Fody.PropertyChanged: https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged. This removes the need to add your own boilerplate code with these issues.

Comment: Can you write simple example of fody using in answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of doing the PropertyChanged yourself, you can also use Fody.PropertyChanged. (https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged)

You can install it via Nuget in Visual Studio.

What is does it automaticly adds the PropertyChanged implementation when compiling.

Your code:

```
using PropertyChanged;

[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class Person 
{        
    public string GivenNames { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", GivenNames, FamilyName);
        }
    }
}
```

What gets compiled:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    string givenNames;
    public string GivenNames
    {
        get { return givenNames; }
        set
        {
            if (value != givenNames)
            {
                givenNames = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("GivenNames");
                OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
            }
        }
    }

    string familyName;
    public string FamilyName
    {
        get { return familyName; }
        set 
        {
            if (value != familyName)
            {
                familyName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FamilyName");
                OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
            }
        }
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", GivenNames, FamilyName);
        }
    }

    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null)
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

There are also other features, please read them at the wiki: https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki

Comment: After installing Fody.Validar i get error "The type or namespace name 'ImplementPropertyChangedAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Add 
using PropertyChanged;

Comment: The type or namespace name 'PropertyChanged' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) and in FodyWeaver i added "  <Fielder />
<PropertyChanged/>"

Comment: after installing from nuget PropertyChanged.Fody it's working very well. Thanks!

Comment: OMG that is so lovely. I now have a big project with shared code where I only want INPC in one project. Now, with preprocessor directives I'll be able to make it INPC, hope it's gonna work.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old and doesn't *exactly* answer your question.  I thought this would be a better solution for you.

Bindable uses a dictionary as a property store. It's easy enough to add the necessary overloads for a subclass to manage its own backing field using ref parameters.

- No magic string
- No reflection
- Can be improved to suppress the default dictionary lookup

The code:

```
    public class Bindable : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Dictionary<string, object> _properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the value of a property
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="name"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected T Get<T>([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            object value = null;
            if (_properties.TryGetValue(name, out value))
                return value == null ? default(T) : (T)value;
            return default(T);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the value of a property
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="value"></param>
        /// <param name="name"></param>
        protected void Set<T>(T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            if (Equals(value, Get<T>(name)))
                return;
            _properties[name] = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(name);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

used like this

```
public class Item : Bindable
{
     public Guid Id { get { return Get<Guid>(); } set { Set<Guid>(value); } }
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised that there's only few votes, this deserves more

Comment: @Keytrap thank you for the recognition!  i still use this in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to invoke `OnPropertyChanged("Name");`
the best place is on the Name poperty setter.

Answer (score 1):

Very convenient way to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` is to implement a following method in your class:

```
protected virtual bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(storage, value))
        return false;

    storage = value;
    this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

    return true;
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
private string _foo;
public string Foo 
{
    get { return this._foo; }
    set { SetProperty(ref this._foo, value); }
}
```

However, because you are making a wrapper to other class, you can't use references to properties in your `CustomerViewModel` class. This can be worked around, but it will lead to writing a massive amount of code just to properly implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Instead of wrapping your `Customer` class into some other, make it a public property instead:

```
private Customer _customer;
public Customer Customer 
{
    get { return this._customer; }
    private set { SetProperty(ref this._customer, value); }
}
```

And in your XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding Customer.Name}"></Label>
</Grid>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the great answers above, you can probably achieve this behavior with a DynamicObject wrapper, wrapping the accessed class, and changing its properties on behalf, triggering a property changed event.

I haven't tried it yet (I'd probably go for [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged)), but something like this pseudo might work:

```
public class InpcWrapperViewModel<T> : DynamicObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public T Original { get; }
    public InpcWrapperViewModel(T original)
    {
      Original = original;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
      //set property of Original with reflection etc.
      //raise property changed 
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        //set with reflection etc.
        return true;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
dynamic x = new InpcWrapperViewModel<TEntity>(entity);
window.DataContext = x;
x.FirstName = "Hello"; //triggers INPC
```

If you're using Prism or any other DI etc. you can create a ViewModel factory that wraps the items automatically.

Again, the above is pseudo code never tested or tried.